# Load data from a controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a drilldown screens flow:

```
Teams
    Team 1
        Player 1
        Player 2
        Player 3
        Player 4
    Team 2
        Player 1
        Player 2
        Player 3
    Team 3
        Player 1
```

For each I have its own controller:

```
TeamsCtrl > TeamCtrl > PlayerCtrl
```

Also each team and player has its own url that are used by Angular to identify items:

```
/teams/1/players/3
```

Now, When I visit `/teams` url, it runs a function inside `TeamsCtrl` which loads all data and I can go to each nested item and see all the data. It works fine.

But, if I go straight to a team url like `/teams/1`, or a player url like `/teams/1/players/2`, that function doesn't run because it's not present nor in `TeamCtrl` neither in `PlayerCtrl` so the whole dataset is empty now.

I feel like running that fetching function every time I switch between players or teams is not right. So, how do I make sure that I have all the data if I go by links not from top to bottom in hierarchy but arbitrary?

Comment: Unless you can guarantee how a user of your SPA will navigate, you may want to consider fetching all the data in each controller.  The app will depend a lot less on state, which should ensure that a user can jump around arbitrarily and the app will handle it robustly.

Comment: are you using $routeProvider?

Comment: Create a service and add a `resolve` in main teams `state` so that you have the teams data anywhere in that state regardless of where user enters

Comment: Put the API call in a Service. Don't store the data in the Service, just the API call, and maybe any post-process functions you may need to run the data through. Call that Service function in each controller that needs the data. If you're worried about the inefficiency of calling for the same data everywhere, cache it (there are tools for this built in).

Comment: Thanks for advice. Yes, I use an Angular service, which I run from the main controller. Seems like I will need to do caching and call it in each controller.

Answer (score 0):

Recommendation is to create a service that wraps the data structures themselves, and include methods on the service that retrieve the data set that you require at each level.

Once created, inject the service into each of the controllers. Plus side of this is that you load the data just once.

Angular documentation for services is pretty good. Might look something like this.

```
teamDataService.factory('TeamData', ['$resource', function($resource){

// retrieve data from api call of some sort
var tdr = $resource('/path/to/data/service');

var data;


  teamdata = tdr.get(function(){
     data = teamdata; // assuming your api call returns an array of JSON objects.
  };

return {
   teams: function(){
      return data;
   };

   team: function(id){
        return data[id];
   };

   player: function(teamid, playerid){
       return data[teamid].players[playerid];
   };
}

}]);


myApp.controller('teamController', ['$scope', 'TeamData', function($scope, TeamData){

 var Player1 = TeamData.player(1, 1);


}]);
```